# Cannot upload compressed file to Cloud Storage with Python 3 writing with gzip.open()

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

When I try to upload a compressed gzip file to cloud storage using a python script on a Cloud Shell instance, it always upload an empty file.

Here's the code to reproduce the errors:

```
import gzip
from google.cloud import storage

storage_client = storage.Client()

list=['hello', 'world', 'please', 'upload']

out_file=gzip.open('test.gz', 'wt')
    for line in list:
    out_file.write(line + '\n')
out_file.close

out_bucket = storage_client.bucket('test-bucket')
out_blob = out_bucket.blob('test')
out_blob.upload_from_filename('test.gz')
```

It uploads only an empty file named 'test' on my bucket which is not what I expect.

However, my file written in my Cloud Shell is not empty because when I do `zcat test.gz` it shows the expected content:

```
hello
world
please
upload
```

Comment: Hi @Dondi, I will check your answer next week as I can't test it right now, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To understand what's happening in your code, here's a description from [gzip docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html#gzip.GzipFile):

> *Calling a GzipFile object’s close() method **does not close fileobj**, since you might wish to append more material after the compressed data.*

This explains why file objects not being closed affects the upload of your file. Here's a [supporting answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62669877/7031308) which describes the behavior of your code where  the fileobj is not being closed, where:

> *The warning about fileobj not being closed only applies when you open the file, and pass it to the GzipFile via the fileobj= parameter. When you pass only a filename, GzipFile "owns" the file handle and will also close it.*

The solution is to not pass the gzipfile via `fileobj = parameter` and to rewrite it like this:

```
import gzip
from google.cloud import storage

storage_client = storage.Client()

list=['hello', 'world', 'please', 'upload']

with gzip.open('test.gz', 'rt') as f_in, gzip.open('test.gz', 'wt') as f_out: 
  for line in list:
    f_out.writelines(line + '\n')

out_bucket = storage_client.bucket('test-bucket')
out_blob = out_bucket.blob('test.gz') # include file format in dest filename
out_blob.upload_from_filename("test.gz")
```