# Gzip a file in Python before uploading to Cloud Storage

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, gzip

I have the following Python function to write the given content to a bucket in Cloud Storage:

```
import gzip
from google.cloud import storage

def upload_to_cloud_storage(json):
    """Write to Cloud Storage."""

    # The contents to upload as a JSON string.
    contents = json

    storage_client = storage.Client()

    # Path and name of the file to upload (file doesn't yet exist).
    destination = "path/to/name.json.gz"

    # Gzip the contents before uploading
    with gzip.open(destination, "wb") as f:
        f.write(contents.encode("utf-8"))

    # Bucket
    my_bucket = storage_client.bucket('my_bucket')

    # Blob (content)
    blob = my_bucket.blob(destination)
    blob.content_encoding = 'gzip'

    # Write to storage
    blob.upload_from_string(contents, content_type='application/json')
```

However, I receive an error when running the function:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'path/to/name.json.gz'
```

Highlighting this line as the cause:

```
with gzip.open(destination, "wb") as f:
```

I can confirm that the bucket and path both exist although the file itself is new and to be written.

I can also confirm that removing the Gzipping part sees the file successfully written to Cloud Storage.

**How can I gzip a new file and upload to Cloud Storage?**

Other answers I've used for reference:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/54769937
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/67995040

Comment: If you get a `FileNotFoundError` while opening the file for writing, you most likely specified the wrong path. Check the current working directory or use an absolute path and try again

Comment: The file doesn't actually exist at that point (just the path). Following this example(https://stackoverflow.com/a/54769937/127427), I'm creating a new gzip file. Is this not the correct way to create a new gzip file?

Comment: I meant that if you are trying to write to `./path/to/name.json.gz` and you get `No such file or directory` it most likely means that the directory `./path` and/or the directory `./path/to` does not exist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although @David's answer wasn't complete at the time of solving my problem, it got me on the right track. Here's what I ended up using along with explanations I found out along the way.

```py
import gzip

from google.cloud import storage
from google.cloud.storage import fileio 

def upload_to_cloud_storage(json_string):
    """Gzip and write to Cloud Storage."""

    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.bucket('my_bucket')

    # Filename (include path)
    blob = bucket.blob('path/to/file.json')

    # Set blog meta data for decompressive transcoding
    blob.content_encoding = 'gzip'
    blob.content_type = 'application/json'

    writer = fileio.BlobWriter(blob)

    # Must write as bytes
    gz = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=writer, mode="wb")

    # When writing as bytes we must encode our JSON string.
    gz.write(json_string.encode('utf-8'))

    # Close connections
    gz.close()
    writer.close()
```

We use the [GzipFile() class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html#gzip.GzipFile) instead of convenience method ([compress](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html#gzip.compress)) to enable us to pass in the mode. When trying to write using `w` or `wt` you will receive the error:

```
TypeError: memoryview: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

So we must write in binary mode (`wb`). This will also enable the `.write()` method. When doing so however we need to encode our JSON string. This can be done using `str.encode()` and setting it as `utf-8`. Failing to do this will also result in the same error.

Finally, I wanted to be able to enable [decompressive transcoding](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/transcoding#decompressive_transcoding) where the requester (browser in my case) will receive the uncompressed version of the file when requested. To enable this `google.cloud.storage.blob` allows you to set some meta data including [content_type](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/blobs.html#google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob.content_type) and [content_encoding](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/blobs.html#google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob.content_encoding) so we can can follow [best practices](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/transcoding#good_practices).

This sees the JSON object in memory written to your chosen destination in Cloud Storage in a compressed format and decompressed on the fly (without needing to download a gzip archive).

Thanks also to @JohnHanley for the troubleshooting advice.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution is not to write the gzip to a file at all, and directly compress and stream to GCS.

```py
from google.cloud import storage
from google.cloud.storage import fileio 

storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.bucket('my_bucket')
blob = bucket.blob('my_object')
writer = fileio.BlobWriter(blob)
gz = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=writer, mode="w")  # use "wb" if bytes
gz.write(contents)
gz.close()
writer.close()
```

Comment: Thanks @David. Is this instead of `upload_from_string()`? Can I still set the content type as `application/json` and `Content-Encoding` as `gzip` for decompressive transcoding? (https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/transcoding#content-type_vs_content-encoding)

Comment: @ianyoung - I recommend trying David's solution to your original question. If you have another problem or question create a new question with your new code.

Comment: I'm getting `NameError: name 'BlobWriter' is not defined`. Which library does this come from?

Comment: I can now import `BlobWriter` but then get `unexpected keyword argument 'fileobject'`. If i remove `fileobject` as a named argument. I then get `TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not BlobWriter`. I'm a little lost in what it is I'm supposed to be doing. I appreciate the suggestion but I could do with a little more info as to why it would be a better option. The only streaming example I can find in the docs is this one (https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/samples/storage-stream-file-upload) but it is very different from the suggestion. Any ideas how to get it working?

Comment: @ianyoung - the first step is to review the documentation for each API that you use. That way you can look up and solve minor issues. Change `fileobject` to `fileobj`. See this link: https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html#gzip.GzipFile

Comment: Thanks @JohnHanley. I feel I'm getting close. However I'm receiving another error `OSError(errno.EBADF, "write() on read-only GzipFile object")` on the `gzip` line. I have tried attaching `mode=rb` as well as `rt`, `wb`, and `wt`. All to no avail. I'm not sure why it is a read-only object and how to change that other than changing `mode`.

Comment: @ianyoung - create a new post with your current code.